# Normalization of custom PDF

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I needed to implement a couple of probability density functions li:

```
import numpy as np

def bekkers(x, a, m, d):
    P = a*np.exp((-1*(x**(1/3) - m)**2)/(2*d**2))*np.power(x, -2/3)
    return(P)
```

The problem is, it has no intrinsic normalization, so it has to be normalized by hand. I tried using scipy.integrate.quad for computing the integral of the function from 0 to infinity, and using it as a denominator for P, but it is extremely slow and it interferes with the optimization when I try to use the function for the nonlinear fitting. What is the most elegant and fast way to do this?

Comment: Is the normalization necessary for your later optimization? Can you give a minimal example of your optimizaiton problem?

Comment: @William Zhang, I use this function to fit the histograms using scipy.optimize.curve_fit. The normalization is necessary because the PDF describes the probability density for the whole range of values.

Comment: If you're doing maximum likelihood estimation to estimate the three parameters a, m, and d, then the normalization constant is not necessary.

Comment: No, curve_fit uses Levenberg-Marquardt least squares algorythm.